# Content does not center correctly in CSS | Justify-content center

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I need to centralize the content the same way it is there. When I use justify-content:center it gets broken.

[image]

With the justify content center, it looks like this:

[image]

HTML / JSX

```
    <div className={styles.contentBodyTab}>
      <div className={styles.containerBrands}>
        {data.map((item) => (
          <div className={styles.brand} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS (SASS)

```
.contentBodyTab {
  background: red;
}

.containerBrands {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.brand {
   background: chartreuse;
   margin: 2px;
   width: 190px;
   height: 130px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT:** *I based my answer on that I thought you had your desired outcome in the first screenshot. If this is not true, please update your post with the desired outcome* :)

You need to add `display: flex;` and `justify-content: flex-start;` to:

```
<div key={String(item)} className={styles.containerBrand}>
  {..}
</div>
```

This works:

```css
.contentBodyTab {
  background: red;
}
.containerBrand {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.brand {
  background: chartreuse;
  margin: 2px;
  width: 190px;
  height: 130px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentBodyTab">
  <div class="containerBrands">
    <div class="containerBrand">
      <div class="brand"></div>
      <div class="brand"></div>
      <div class="brand"></div>
      <div class="brand"></div>
      <div class="brand"></div>
      <div class="brand"></div>
      <div class="brand"></div>
      <div class="brand"></div>
      <div class="brand"></div>
      <div class="brand"></div>
      <div class="brand"></div>
      <div class="brand"></div>
      <div class="brand"></div>
      <div class="brand"></div>
      <div class="brand"></div>
      <div class="brand"></div>
      <div class="brand"></div>
      <div class="brand"></div>
      <div class="brand"></div>
      <div class="brand"></div>
      <div class="brand"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It didn't work, bro!

Comment: I improved my question.